# Why does my int variable change when I've already set it?

Tags: objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I've placed a `UIPanGestureRecognizer on my table view:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeCell:)];
swipe.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
swipe.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
swipe.delegate = self;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

I am trying to set the initial touch y coordinate to `initialY` var. I try to do this by setting it when the `swipe.state` is equal to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. The purpose of this is to use it when `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` but in this method, `initalY` is set to `1`. Why is this?

```
    -(void)closeCell:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

        CGPoint pointInView = [swipe locationInView:swipe.view];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInView];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        int initalY;
        int changeInMovement = 0;

        if (indexPath == expandIndexPath) {

            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

            if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
                CGPoint pointInCell = [swipe locationInView:cell];
                initalY = pointInCell.y;

                NSLog(@"BEGAN");
                NSLog(@"INITIAL Y: %d", initalY);

            }

            if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
                CGPoint pointInCell = [swipe locationInView:cell];
                int currentY = pointInCell.y;
                changeInMovement = initalY - currentY;
                NSLog(@"initial Y: %d", initalY);
                NSLog(@"current Y: %d", currentY);
                NSLog(@"change in Y: %d", changeInMovement);

                //THE PROBLEM IS THAT INITAL Y BECOMES 1

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a local variable. It will be "created" fresh each time the method is called.

You could make the variable static, which will preserve it's value. A static variable is shared between instances (e.g. all viewControllers with the same class) and between method calls. Just add the keyword `static`:

```
static int initalY = 0;
static int changeInMovement = 0;
```

Comment: newbie mistake. Thank you :)